# 3 column grid layout spaced out over width with dynamic content

Tags: css, css-grid

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the following layout with dynamic content:

code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <span>Published</span>
   <span>Song title</span>
   <span>Edit song</span>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to go about it, taking into account that sometimes the texts in each span don't always appear, I want they layout to be fixed so that even if one of the texts doesn't appear they always remain in the same place. Thanks!

The original code above I tried with `display:flex` doesn't work because when the text doesn't appear the grid collapses.

Comment: Please provide what you've tried so far. Asking volunteers to do your work for you is not very nice...

Comment: I originally tried the answer @Matthew provided but the grid collapses

Comment: [edit] your question to include what you've tried, what doesn't work about it, and what exactly you want to happen that the code you've tried doesn't. BTW, the fact that you already tried the answer, had it been included in the question, would have save Matthew some time...

Comment: Ok I've updated it now sorry

Comment: You will have to show what _"...when the text doesn't appear the grid collapses"_ actually mean.

Answer (score -1):

add the following css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hxazcg71/

Comment: Explanation, explanation, explanation... most important part of an answer (even if it is a small one), so start adding that and you'll get upvotes instead of downvote, but more importantly, help the asker to understand what you suggest mean/does/work.